# Intellij IDEA Kotlin Android Theme.AppCompat No Resource Found

Tags: android, intellij-idea, kotlin, android-appcompat

I wanna build and run `Kotlin` code from this repository

https://github.com/steelkiwi/Getting-started-with-Kotlin

But, it always give this error when I built it

> Error:(3, -1) android-apt-compiler: [main] Error retrieving parent for
>   item: No resource found that matches the given name
>   'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

I had googling about this error, and some of the answers suggest to add AppCompat manually to project. I have been try those solution, and get the same result.

I used Intelllij IDEA and I just think, this problem was on my IDE configuration. I have enable Android Support, and no result.

Is there anyone have same problem like this on Intellij IDEA?

Comment: Did you change something? Because I just cloned the repo and runned `./gradlew assembleDebug` and the build was successfull.

Comment: Nothing, but I run `build` through the IDE. not run that command on terminal

Comment: And what happens if you run this command directly in your terminal?

Comment: I have try it and `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`. But when I wanna run the application using the IDE the error keep exist

Comment: I just tried with Android Studio and it works well. Android Studio is a fork of Intellij and it's specially adapted for Android development. You should give it a try.